# ASP.NET Dynamic Validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have this issue where I have two check boxes that I am trying to validate, so one of them must be chosen.

I am creating the method using javascript which is :

```
    function learningDisValidator(source, args) {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= persLearningDisabilityYes.ClientID %>").checked || document.getElementById("<%= persLearningDisabilityNo.ClientID %>").checked) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }

    }
```

than I have the custom field validator which is

```
    <asp:CustomValidator id="learningDisVal" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" ErrorMessage="Learning Disability is Required" ClientValidationFunction="learningDisValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Now this Validator for some reason is not working. My problem is that I have other validators that are enabled during runtime if certain options are selected using

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('persLearningDisabilityDetailsVal'), true);
```

and these do work. The problem I have with these validators that are enabled during runtime is that the error message is displayed as soon as they are enabled, not after the Submit button was clicked.I am rather new to ASP.NET. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT : I have other validators that are enabled depending on the users choice, for example if Radio button 1 was checked, it will show new form fields and enable validators for "MAN" and if radio button 2 was checked it will show new form fields and enabled validators for "WOMAN". Now my problem is that once the validator is enabled, as I showed above, it's error message is being shown instantly in the error panel in the bottom of the screen, which is basically a div with the asp.net custom validator in it. I would like this message to be shown after the Submit button was clicked, thus giving the user time to figure out on his "own" not telling him that something is required before giving him the chance to do it. As for code I not know what else to give but I'll try :

```
<div class="col1of1val"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="accHostFamilyDetailsAllergiesVal" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="accHostFamilyDetailsAllergies" ErrorMessage="field cannot be empty" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
```

and in javascript:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('accHostFamilyDetailsAllergiesVal'), true);
```

Comment: I'd be glad to help though, could you provide a more complete example of your code?

Comment: Don't if my edit did help, I just hope it did :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The CustomValidator fires before the page's post. You want it to fire after. Right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need, but when it fires I would like it to be removed dynamically depending if the Validation passes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Jquery and check if both values are null before the form submits. So something like this.

Test for "", if that doesn't work test for 0

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

if ($("#checkbox1").val() == "" && $("#checkbox2").val() == "")
 {
    // causes form submit to stop and will not post to the server
      alert("some error message");
     return false;
 }

});
```

Comment: well i can check using 

        $("#checkbox1").checked == false

but this is not what i required.